# isalpha in c++ not working correctly for single integer

Tags: c++, vector, ctype, isalpha

I made a code to convert nfa to dfa using stl(vectors). 
In this code isalpha() is not working.
The *if block* below isalpha doesnt do anything.
If i enter an alphabet it prints all the **cout** below it
I tried using

```
if(isaplha(n){
cout<<"Incorrect";
return 0;
}
```

It's still not working
If you could suggest anything that will be great. Also if you feel the code needs any improvement please tell

```
#include<ctype.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void print(vector<vector<vector<int> > > table){
    cout<<setw(10)<<"STATE/INPUT";
    char a='a';
    for(int i=0;i<table[0].size()-1;i++){
        cout<<setw(10)<<a++<<setw(10);
    }
    cout<<"^"<<endl<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        cout<<"-";
        cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<table.size();i++){
        cout<<setw(10)<<i;
        for(int j=0;j<table[i].size();j++){
            cout<<setw(10);
            for(int k=0;k<table[i][j].size();k++){
                cout<<table[i][j][k]<<" ";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
void printdfa(vector<vector<int> > states, vector<vector<vector<int> > > dfa){
    cout<<"  STATE/INPUT  ";
    char a='a';
    for(int i=0;i<dfa[0].size();i++){
        cout<<setw(11)<<a++<<setw(10);
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        cout<<"-";
        cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<states.size();i++){
        cout<<setw(11)<<"{ ";
        for(int h=0;h<states[i].size();h++)
            cout<<states[i][h];
        if(states[i].empty()){
            cout<<"^";
        }
        cout<<" }";
        for(int j=0;j<dfa[i].size();j++){
            cout<<setw(11);
            for(int k=0;k<dfa[i][j].size();k++){
                cout<<dfa[i][j][k]<<" ";
            }
            if(dfa[i][j].empty()){
                cout<<"^";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
vector<int> closure(int s,vector<vector<vector<int> > > v){
    vector<int> t;
    queue<int> q;
    t.push_back(s);
    int a=v[s][v[s].size()-1].size();
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        t.push_back(v[s][v[s].size()-1][i]);
        q.push(t[i]);
    }
    while(!q.empty()){
        int f=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(!v[f][v[f].size()-1].empty()){
            int u=v[f][v[f].size()-1].size();
            for(int i=0;i<u;i++){
                int y=v[f][v[f].size()-1][i];
                if(find(t.begin(),t.end(),y)==t.end()){
                    t.push_back(y);
                    q.push(y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}
int main(){
    int n,alpha;
    cout<<"************************* NFA to DFA *************************"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter total number of states in NFA : ";
    cin>>n;
    if(isalpha(n) != 0){
        cout<<"Incorrect";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"Enter number of elements in alphabet : ";
    cin>>alpha;
    if(isalpha(alpha) != 0){
        cout<<"Incorrect";
        return 0;
    }
    vector<vector<vector<int> > > table;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"For state "<<i<<endl;
        vector< vector< int > > v;
        char a='a';
        int y,yn;
        for(int j=0;j<alpha;j++){
            vector<int> t;
            cout<<"Enter no. of output states for input "<<a++<<" : ";
            cin>>yn;
            cout<<"Enter output states :"<<endl;
            for(int k=0;k<yn;k++){
                cin>>y;
                t.push_back(y);
            }
            v.push_back(t);
        }
        vector<int> t;
        cout<<"Enter no. of output states for input ^ : ";
        cin>>yn;
        cout<<"Enter output states :"<<endl;
        for(int k=0;k<yn;k++){
            cin>>y;
            t.push_back(y);
        }
        v.push_back(t);
        table.push_back(v);
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"***** TRANSITION TABLE OF NFA *****"<<endl<<endl;
    print(table);
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<"***** TRANSITION TABLE OF DFA *****"<<endl<<endl;
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> dfa;
    vector<vector<int> > states;
    states.push_back(closure(0,table));
    queue<vector<int> > q;
    q.push(states[0]);
    while(!q.empty()){
        vector<int> f=q.front();
        q.pop();
        vector<vector<int> > v;
        for(int i=0;i<alpha;i++){
            vector<int> t;
            set<int> s;
            for(int j=0;j<f.size();j++){
                for(int k=0;k<table[f[j]][i].size();k++){
                    vector<int> cl= closure(table[f[j]][i][k],table);
                    for(int h=0;h<cl.size();h++){
                        if(s.find(cl[h])==s.end())
                        s.insert(cl[h]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for(set<int >::iterator u=s.begin(); u!=s.end();u++)
                t.push_back(*u);
            v.push_back(t);
            if(find(states.begin(),states.end(),t)==states.end())
            {
                states.push_back(t);
                q.push(t);
            }
        }
        dfa.push_back(v);
    }
    printdfa(states,dfa);
}
```

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: @Priyank Could you provide a minimal program that demonstrates the problem without your vectors of vectors?

Comment: `int n; cin>>n;` doesn't allow non-number inputs, and you never checked if the operation succeeded or failed.

Comment: @Mooing Duck cin>>n allow single char input. How to check if operation succeeded or failed?

Comment: No it doesn't.  `cin>>n` (when `n` is an `int`) allows a single _integer_ input, between -2000000000ish and +2000000000ish (note: that's up to 11 chars).  It doesn't allow any other characters.

Comment: Keep an eye out for misleading indentation. `for(int i=0;i<50;i++) cout<<"-"; cout<<endl; cout<<endl;` does not loop the first `endl` in spite of the indentation. I recommend always using the braces while learning because it makes whole families of bugs impossible.

Comment: @bhristov Your answer was almost right. It just needed some more explanation and a small tweak.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve], focus on minimal!? Only a few lines from the start of main are necessary to show what you mean. The rest is unnecessary bloat that makes it harder for everyone to find the relevant stuff to help you.

Comment: The `cin >> n` will fail if the input is not an integer.  The `isalpha` is for characters, not numbers.

Comment: I recommend being nicer when the program fails.  Don't output "incorrect", prefer to tell the User why it is incorrect, e.g. "Invalid input, expected number".

Comment: `isalpha` works, it just doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple method for testing the correct input of numbers is to test the operation:

```
if (!(cin >> n))
{
  std::cerr << "Invalid input, expected number".
  return 0;
}
```

However, this does not catch the following cases:
1b683 -- Input stops at "b" and returns the value 1
3.14159 -- Input stops at "." and returns the value 3.

To catch the above exceptions, you'll probably need to implement parsing, or maybe regular expression.  Both are more complicated for simple programs.